# I have a shopify shop and i want to be able to see when my stock is sold out?

Tags: php, javascript, html, e-commerce, shopify

I have a shop developed in shopify and i want to be able to see when an item is sold out on the order form of my website in the backend area.

Basically when someone buys a product that us out of stock, i receive an order form with there details and the details of the product they bought, however i would like a notice within this form that tells me this item is out of stock.

I have done this piece of coding, however it does not seem to be working??

```
<td class="item-product">
    <div class="cart">
      <a href="{{item.product.url }}">{{item.product.title}}</a>
      <a href="{{item/order.url }}">{{item.order.title}}</a>
      <br />
      <strong>Size :</strong> {{item.variant.title}}
      {% if item.variant.available == true %}
          {% if item.variant.inventory_quantity > 0 %}  
          {% else %}
              <p style="color:red;"> 
                  Item is currently being restocked and will take an extra
                  3-4 weeks to ship
              </p>
          {% endif %}
      {% endif %}   
    </div>
</td>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You'll have better luck asking this on the Shopify support forum. You probably won't find many Shopify experts here.

Comment: I agree with @Diodeus. Try the support forum.  That or provide a jsfiddle example.

Comment: Shopify uses their own templating system, so this isn't just a simple PHP question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might have an idea for you.

First, here is how I understand your problem:  You would like some sort of automatic notification when the inventory levels of one of your products crosses below a certain threshold.  So, if your inventory of Green Steel Widgets drops below 10, you want to know about it so you can re-stock ASAP.

Provided I'm on the right track, here's my idea.

1. First, open the Shopify Admin.  Then, open the Preferences menu, and click the "Email & Notifications" item.
2. Open the "New Order Notification" template (top row, second item).  Look at the PLAIN TEXT template (the first one on the page once you open this template).  Please note that customers DO NOT see this email.  Only you, so feel free to get creative with it!
3. Assuming you have not already modified this template, the last three lines should look something like this:

   ```
   {% for line in line_items %}{{ line.quantity }}x {{line.title }}        (sku: {{ line.sku }})
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   Replace those two lines with the following three lines

   ```
   {% for line in line_items %}{{ line.quantity }}x {{line.title }}        (sku: {{ line.sku }})
   {% if line.variant.inventory_management && line.variant.inventory_quantity < 10 %}****WARNING! SKU: {{line.sku}} HAS LOW INVENTORY****{% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

The result of all this will be a plain-text email notification that looks something like the following when you have items whose inventory drops below 10.

```
Store Owner,

Bob Biller placed a new order with you today (Jan 11 06:51PM). 

Payment method:
  paypal

Delivery method: 
  Generic Shipping

Shipping address:
  Steve Shipper
    123 Shipping Street
    Shippington, Kentucky  K2P0S0
    United States
    555-555-SHIP


1x Sledgehammer        (sku: SKU2006-001)
****WARNING! SKU: SKU2006-001 HAS LOW INVENTORY****
1x Wire Cutter        (sku: SKU2006-020)
****WARNING! SKU: SKU2006-020 HAS LOW INVENTORY****
```

This is very simple example, but it hopefully can give you some ideas for how you could use the Order Notification email as an inventory alert mechanism.  You can get a LOT fancier if you enable the HTML version of this notification and throw in some Liquid logic there.

Hope this helps!  Good luck!

---

## UPDATE (2013-01-13)

---

In comments, the Original Poster clarified that they would like to have the "Low Inventory Warning" somehow show up inside the Order Details page of the Shopify Admin Interface.  I've edited my answer to show one way of doing this.

### Add Low Inventory Warnings as Line-Item Custom Attributes

Somewhere inside your `cart.liquid` file, you will find the for-loop that builds the HTML each line item in your customer's cart. The code will look something like this:

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
```

Now, somewhere inside that for-loop, you *should* be able to find a line with an HTML `<input>` tag.  Add the following code to a new line, directly beneath that tag.

```
{% assign post_sale_inventory_count = item.variant.inventory_quantity | minus: item.quantity %}

{% if item.variant.inventory_management == "shopify" and post_sale_inventory_count < 10 %}
    <input type="hidden" name="attributes[{{item.variant.id}}-ALERT]" value="INVENTORY LOW FOR SKU: {{item.variant.sku}}" />
{% endif %}
```

What this will do is create a hidden `<input>` field for each line item whose product variant inventory would go below 10 if this order were to be placed as-is.

If the customer actually places this order, then the Shopify Admin Order Page should have something like the following in the notes section.

```
123456-ALERT: INVENTORY LOW FOR SKU: ADM9500-YELOW-LRG

654321-ALERT: INVENTORY LOW FOR SKU: FRSB965-XL-CS
```

---

### UPDATE 2 (2013-01-14)

---

I made some syntax and structure errors with my sample code. I've fixed them and added the correct code to this answer.  I've tested this on a test shop, and I know for sure it works.  Please give it a go and let me know if you have any trouble.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, Thank you, that works okay, however i also need a note that shows up in the orders page, that is invisible to customers and only visible to the store owner that says you are nearly out of stock, i was told earlier by someone that this can be done by going into the cart.liquid page and cart attributes page and by adding in some code, however i am still unsure of what i need to code in to those pages and all my attempts so far have not worked out.

Comment: Ahhh...OK.  Now I see where you're going.  You're right, the only way to do what you want is to add a custom attribute inside of the cart.liquid page, but ONLY if that order will take inventory below your low inventory threshold.  Give me a few hours and I'll try to post a code sample for you.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail about what exactly did not work?

Comment: Hello again!  I found out why my code was not working, and I fixed it.  I've tested the code, and it works as I described it.  Could you please copy the new code from the sample in my answer and give it another try?  Also, if this works out for you, could you please mark my post as the correct answer to your question?  Thank you!

Comment: That's great! I'm glad I could help! Thank you very much for marking my post as the answer. :-)

Comment: Hi, is there anyway i can actually make it that it only tells me when im totally out of stock, like -1 in stock?

Comment: Sure! Just change  `post_sale_inventory_count < 10` to `post_sale_inventory_count < 1`.